# How can I modify my for loop so it doesn't compare the first and last, but compares everything else to last?

Tags: java, polygon

For example I have a list of points here

List = <1,1>, <99,99>, <199,1>, <210,99>

I want <1,1> to compare with <99,99> and with <199,1> but not <210,99> 
but everything else can compare to <210,99>

basically the first and last element cannot compare because this would imply my polygon is closed.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < this.points.size()-1; i++) {
        Point firstPoint = this.points.get(i);
        for(int j = i+1; j < this.points.size(); j++)   {
            Point secondPoint = this.points.get(j);

            Line2D line1 = new Line2D.Double(firstPoint.getX(), firstPoint.getY(), secondPoint.getX(), secondPoint.getY());
            Line2D line2 = new Line2D.Double(((Line) aLine).getStart().getX(),((Line) aLine).getStart().getY(),((Line) aLine).getEnd().getX(),((Line) aLine).getEnd().getY());
            boolean result = line2.intersectsLine(line1);
            if(!result) {

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired output as following:

```
boolean isFirstElement = true;
for (int i = 0; i < pList.size() - 1; i++) {
    Point pointOne = pList.get(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < pList.size(); j++) {
        Point pointTwo = pList.get(j);
        if (j + 1 == pList.size() && isFirstElement) {
            continue;
        } else {
            // your comparison logic goes here...
        }
    }
    isFirstElement = false;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to take the extra variable `isFirstElement`. `if (j + 1 == pList.size() && i == 0)` would do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition `(i != 0 || j != this.points.size() - 1)` to the inner loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.points.size()-1; i++) {
    Point firstPoint = this.points.get(i);
    for(int j = i + 1; j < this.points.size() && (i != 0 || j != this.points.size() - 1); j++) {
     ....
    }
}
```

If not, you can add a `continue` statement if `i == 0` and `j == this.points.szie() - 1`